# Menu doesn't show up on the actionbar

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm trying to create a menu for my `actvity`. But it can not show up on the `actionbar` like I do. Just help me where wrong.

This is my **menu**.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.sship.MainActivity" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_about_app"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_help"/>
```

This is my **activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search button selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "About button selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.help:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Help button selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

And this is result

[image: result]

Comment: emulator with api 16

Comment: Would you please provide the styles.xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pre Android 4.4, device has a hardware menu button,so action overflow menu is activated with the hardware button and thus overflow icon is not shown.**

**You have to do this forcefully in pre-4.4 devices** to show action overflow button. Try below code in your activity's `onCreate()` method

```
ViewConfiguration configure = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
Field menuField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
if (menuField != null) {
    menuField.setAccessible(true);
    menuField.setBoolean(config, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using the default toolbar defined by the styles.xml for example `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

I would recommend that you use a support action bar as it is described by the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up).

**Hint:** The docs tell you to define the NoActionBar theme in the app manifest but you can also set it in the styles.xml so you have more control where to use this action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for your application theme whether it has no action in it.It will be helpful if you share your theme or styles.xml